# How to Scoot Image Up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webstorm

I'm trying to make a grid that will have the bottom image scoot up until it is 10px away from the image above it. Whatever I try, it just goes 10x away from the tallest image. My images in the grid vary in size, so I'm trying to make it look nicer without it, it will just look like a blob of randomly spaced images.

I tried way too much.

```css
.left {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;

}

.right {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.rounded20 {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-right:5px
}

.margin-side {
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left: 5px;

}

.below-image {
    margin-top: 10px; /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wolfy</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .navbar {
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }

        .margin-side {
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .rounded20 {
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        .image-grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
            grid-gap: 10px; /* Set the gap between images to 10px */
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .image-grid img {
            border-radius: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            margin-bottom: -10px; /* Add negative bottom margin to scoot up the image */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navy-blue1 main-text rounded">
    <a href="../index.html" class="brand-text text-light">Wolfy</a>
    <a href="#" class="left text-light">Images</a>
    <img src="../images/Wolfy-banner.png" class="right banner mb-0">
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-grid">
        <img src="../images/wolfy1.jpg" class="rounded20 margin-side">
        <img src="../images/wolfy3.jpg" class="rounded20 margin-side">
        <img src="../images/wolfy4.jpg" class="rounded20 margin-side">
        <img src="../images/wolfy5.jpg" class="rounded20 margin-side">
        <img src="../images/wolfy12.jpg" class="rounded20 margin-side">
        <img src="../images/wolfy13.jpg" class="rounded20 margin-side">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have any JavaScript for it. I'm using WebStorm EAP btw.

I want this:
[image: I want this instead of]

This is what I have:
[image: This]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, can you include a sketch of what you want to achieve and in your snippet include some images we can see.

Comment: I edited it to add images of what i am trying to do

Comment: This is essentially a masonry layout and you'll most likely need JS to do this.

Comment: Idont know js

Comment: You might find that column-count will do enough - it's not a grid.

Comment: dont use a grid?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you A haworth and disinfor, talking about masonry grids and column count, i put it in chatgpt, telling it to make a masonry grid with it and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the code, so that others can benefit too.